# Неправильно выводит

Tags: java, файлы

У меня есть файл чисел, и мне надо, чтобы эти числа вывелись в обратном порядке. Для этого я ставлю данные из файла в коллекцию, ну, и использую метод `reverse`.
В результате мне выводятся данные из файла в таком же порядке, как и в файле.
Пожалуйста, подскажите, что я делаю не так.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Tatiana\\Documents\\nr.txt");
    BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(file);

    String line = " ";
    while ((line = f.readLine()) != null) {


        ArrayList<String> fs=new ArrayList<String>();

        fs.add(line);
        Collections.reverse(fs);
        System.out.println(fs);
```

Comment: Дайте индексируемый заголовок вопросу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    ArrayList<String> fs=new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((line = f.readLine()) != null) {
        fs.add(line);
    }
    Collections.reverse(fs);
    System.out.println(fs);
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо

Comment: @Tanea Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.